# Issues while grafana and kibana integration

Tags: kibana, grafana

I am integrating the kibana and grafana by using the drilldown link to kibana dashboard. The problem is whenever i choose "absolute" option for the drilldown link, and provide a url ex: www.google.com, this url gets prepended with the grafana url, "http://grafanahost/www.google.com". How to get rid of this ?

Comment: I'd move everything to Grafana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try specifying http://www.google.com, it needs to be full URL otherwise browser will see it as local to the webxsite the link is on.